# Whey Protein or Recovery Formula?

Tags: protein, recovery, supplements, p90x

I'm doing P90X and Insanity. I've been taking Amplified Wheybolic Extreme 60 (a whey isolate formula), and it works amazing. I also got the results and recovery formula from beachbody.com when I ordered the workouts, but I haven't used it at all. I'm wondering if it would do me any good to take both, or if I should just stick to the protein. Also, I do one exercise in the morning and one in the evening; should I take both the protein and recovery formula after each exercise, or just stick to one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the ingredients in the P90X Recovery Formula and they included a number of known elements:

- Dextrose & Maltodextrin: a sugar to help provide an insulin spike (40g carbs / serving)
- Whey Protein Concentrate: protein (10g / serving)
- Citric Acid: vitamin C
- L-Carnatine & L-Glutamine: Amino acids associated with fat burning and recovery
- Creatine Monohydrate: helps get energy back into your muscles (500mg / serving)
- Magnesium Oxide: probably the form of magnesium supplement with the lowest absorption rate

An insulin spike after an intense workout helps push energy where it is sorely needed: your muscles.  The common prevailing thought is that that conveys to other needed nutrients like protein.  Whether it truly is cause and effect or simply correlation, your muscles are ready to absorb protein as well post workout.

Without knowing what the percentages of the different ingredients are, these are pretty good recovery supplements.  The problem is the amounts.

Let's contrast this with the AMP Wheybolic Extreme:

- Glutamine, Arginine, Leucine, L-Carnitine: Amino acids associated with fat burning and recovery (Leucine is a Branched Chain Amino Acid)
- AMP marketing ingredients: carbogen and aminogen don't mean anything outside of AMP products, but I'm guessing it provides the same effect as the dextrose/maltodextrin in the P90X Recovery Formula (note: carbs are only 7g / serving)
- Whey Isolate blend: 60g protein / serving

The Wheybolic Extreme supplement is giving you a lot more protein, and some BCAAs which are known to help with recovery.  Between the two supplements this provides a better recovery solution.  The only thing that concerns me are the marketing ingredients.  There really isn't any way to tell what they do for or to you without relying on the AMP marketing hype.

What's missing that could make it better is some Creatine Monohydrate (the only form of Creatine with loads of research behind it and proven results).  The recommended dose of Creatine Monohydrate is about 5g / day.  When you exercise your muscles burn ATP with a byproduct of ADP and lactic acid.  Creatine helps convert the ADP back to ATP, allowing you to do more work.  It is hydroscopic which means you'll have some water weight gain with this supplement--but that does not negatively affect your body composition.

As to completing the supplement profile, as long as you have a multivitamin designed for athletic people and possibly a good magnesium supplement you'll have an even better formula than the P90X Recovery Formula.  Chelated magnesium is probably the gold standard and Optimum Nutrition has a very reasonably priced multivitamin.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think one or the other is good. In my opinion, stick with the Amplified Wheybolic Extreme 60. Whey protein formulas are usually among the best, if not the best. I'm not sure exactly what this recovery formula from beachbody.com is, but I can't imagine it being better than Whey, or adding to your results by taking both.

In terms of taking your protein two times a day. I think you should. I remember when I used to work out at P3...a pretty popular training facility for athletes, I got some info from those guys, some of which had PhDs in kinesiology and such. What they told me was this: It's important to take protein 15-30 minutes after a workout if you want to recover fastest and get the most out of your exercise. I can't tell you exactly why, but I'm going to take their word for it. I always had thought up till then as long as you eat within an hour or hour and a half after a workout, you're fine, but they stressed getting a good protein shake in you DIRECTLY after the workout. They even had their own protein mix at the P3 facility to make sure you got it in you.

So as long as you're doing two different types of workouts (training different muscles) I would take the protein right after each workout. I wouldn't recommend  working out the same muscles twice a day though....that can lead to problems down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I would drink something after each workout.

You are doing P90X so I am guessing you are trying to get lean/ripped.  If you start dabbling into multiple kinds of supplements I would recommend monitoring your bowel movements.  Your body can only handle getting so much bigger or processing so much protein but it can take in tons of calories.  If you have too much #2 you need to cut the supplements down/out.

Also nothing wrong with 16 ounces of chocolate milk after a workout.